# pppd call won't return

Tags: linux, modem, pppd

I'm having an issue with `pppd call provider` command with a Hayes-compatible modem.

PPPD's version is 2.4.7 which I believe is the latest.

**It fails only when I turn off the modem (i.e. it won't reply to any AT command).**

My chat script is simple:

```
ABORT "BUSY"
ABORT "NO CARRIER"
ABORT "NO DIALTONE"
ABORT "ERROR"
ABORT "NO ANSWER"
TIMEOUT 30
"" AT
OK ATE0
...
```

When modem is turned off `pppd call provider` outputs this:

```
... #bunch of pppd configurations
abort on (BUSY)
abort on (NO CARRIER)
abort on (NO DIALTONE)
abort on (ERROR)
abort on (NO ANSWER)
timeout set to 30 seconds
send (AT^M)
expect (OK)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@....
```

Here I have totally confused.

Facts:

- modem is turned off
- if I send "" to the modem with [minicom](https://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom), it does not answer (as I expect)
- ^@ gets printed forever, it won't stop after 30 seconds. I have to kill it manually with `killall -9 chat; killall -9 pppd`

Even if I change `"" AT` line to `OK AT` (expect OK before sending AT), those ^@ characters are coming:

```
...
timeout set to 30 seconds
expect (OK)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@...
```

Now I have also tested catting this device:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0
^C
```

I waited for 10+ seconds and nothing was printed.

**So my questions are:**

- The [chat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/chat) program should run to error if it does not receive the expected answer, why this one is not doing that? (it obviously does not receive the OK)
- Why is `^M` printed after the `AT` command in the output? (I have done dos2unix for the chat script)

Comment: @Hannu, good point but the modem is inactive! Powered down. If I power it on, the connection succeeds.

Comment: ok, right: I'd take that as a sign of program logic error in pppd. I'll remove that comment as it isn't valid, but keep this; Note: I'd take ^@ as a representation of ascii nul

Comment: pppd is the latest version (2.4.7). Do you think I'll have to dig myself into its code? :/

Comment: Being "the latest" is not necessarily a very effective protection against bugs. ;-) - so, yes if you DO know how to decipher the source and help in improving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is ^M printed after the AT command in the output?

You might have to adjust S3 and S4 (modem CR and LF settings) to match what is expected by the software you're using - or adjust the software settings accordingly.

> The chat program should run to error if it does not receive the expected answer, why this one is not doing that? (it obviously does not receive the OK)

Note that ^@ is a possible representation of ascii nul - the software tries to read the serial port, but fails and either gets a nul character from reading, or fails to recognize the empty read result, tinkering with the string end nul (0x00) - or any variation of that.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set